# How to Perform MalformedURLException / 404 Not Found

Tags: java, http, exception, get, malformedurlexception

How do I make my program return MalformedUrlException and not just a generic Exception?

I am making a simple function that reads a URL a user enters in the console and it returns the content from the URL. I need it to check if the URL is a valid URL or if it's not a working URL.

Example urls:
http://google.com/not-found.html
http:/google.com

I created two catch exceptions but it seems like the overall exception is always returned instead of MalformedUrlException.

```
    public static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
    String content = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        //Create a url connection object 
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        //wrap the url connection a buffered reader 
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content += line + "\n";
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("The following url is invalid'" + theUrl + "'");
        //logging error should go here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong, try agian");
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-: *Throws:
    MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.*

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input with undesirable behaviour?

Comment: @tworogue if I put http:/google.com  or http://google.com/not-found.html I want it to throw a MalformedURlException

Comment: @AhmeeyaGoldman see my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

First, java.net.MalformedURLException is not the case for a "not found" resource:

> public class MalformedURLException extends IOException
>
> Thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal
>   protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could
>   not be parsed.

I understand that you want to catch a situation when the URL results in a not found return code (404). To do this you need to examine the HTTP response code.

The easiest way is to use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

> public abstract class HttpURLConnection extends URLConnection
>
> A URLConnection with support for HTTP-specific features. See the spec
>   for details.
>
> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but
>   the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be
>   transparently shared by other instances. Calling the close() methods
>   on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a
>   request may free network resources associated with this instance but
>   has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the
>   disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent
>   connection is otherwise idle at that time.

You can check the response code by calling `getResponseCode()`. If the result is less than 400, you got a valid response, otherwise there was a client error (4xx) or a server error (5xx).

Something like this:

```
public static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) {
    String content = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        //Create a url connection object 
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
            if (conn.getResponseCode() < 400) {
                // read contents
            } else {
                System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
                // treat the error as you like
            }
        } else {
            // not a HTTP connection, treat as you like
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("The following url is invalid'" + theUrl + "'");
        //logging error should go here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong, try agian");
    }
    return content;
}
```

I have not checked the code, but I think you can get the overall idea.